# Replicating a 5-color CSS gradient

Tags: css, colors, gradient, background-color, linear-gradients

I'm trying to replicate the following gradient in CSS:

[image]

The best I've managed to do is:

```
background:
  radial-gradient(ellipse at 20% 20%, #35234b 0%, transparent 70%),
  radial-gradient(ellipse at 60% 20%, #2975bf 0%, transparent 70%),
  radial-gradient(ellipse at 100% 20%, #3d54b1 0%, transparent 70%),
  radial-gradient(ellipse at 100% 100%, #9f3c54 0%, transparent 70%),
  radial-gradient(ellipse at 20% 100%, #362d6f 0%, transparent 70%);
background-blend-mode:screen;
```

which isn't that close:

[image]

Is it possible to get even closer to the gradient in the image? (It doesn't have to be CSS, Javascript is also valid, or even an external library. But pure CSS is preferred.)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 20% 20%, #35234b 0%, transparent 70%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 60% 20%, #2975bf 0%, transparent 70%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 100% 20%, #3d54b1 0%, transparent 70%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 100% 100%, #9f3c54 0%, transparent 70%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 20% 100%, #362d6f 0%, transparent 70%);
  background-blend-mode:screen;
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60209914/8620333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close, start anticlockwise from the left bottom color,
and don't use mix-blend mode- to get rid of artifacts.

```css
body {  
  font: 16px/1.4 sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  min-height: 150vh;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.85); 
  
  background-color: #170d24;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 10% 90%, #3c2d83 0%, transparent 55%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 90% 90%, #c33c65 0%, transparent 55%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 90% 10%, #4a74dc 0%, transparent 55%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 10% 10%, #35244f 0%, transparent 55%);
}
```

```html
<b>ETHEREUM</b> 2.0
<h1>Your Gateway<br>into Blockchain</h1>
<p>Scroll down... and to the moon!</p>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution.
(I added a `radial-gradient(ellipse at 70% 10%, #2975bf 0%, transparent 55%)` for the top mid color, not sure if it's needed)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Temani Afif's suggestion I came up with the following. Still not exact, but way closer than before. If anyone wants to improve on this, it's very much welcome.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #35234b 0% 10%,#2975bf 60% 70%,#3d54b1 80% 100%);
}

body::before{
  content:""; display:block; height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #362d6f,#9f3c54);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent, #fff); 
  mask:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent, #fff);
}
```